# Does universal hashing choose a new hash function again after each operation has been done?

Tags: algorithm, search, hash, insert, universal

I have been reading "Introduction to Algorithms". I was wondering if the universal hashing choose a new one from the collection of hash functions to do the next mapping. For example, given an empty table, and a sequence of operation: [insert, insert, search, delete, insert,...], first, the algorithm choose a function from the collection and do the first operation, insert. Then, does the algorithm choose a new hash function to do the second operation, insert, or use the function chosen at the beginning of the algorithm? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, the hash function is not chosen separately for each inserted element -- if it were, you would need a way of knowing which hash function to use if someone asked you "does the element `foo` exist in the hash table"? This would be done with a deterministic algorithm by necessity, since you cannot possibly maintain a randomized 1-to-1 mapping between possible inputs and hash functions. And *that* in turn means that an attacker could use knowledge of this algorithm to choose inputs that ultimately result in collisions, effectively undoing the advantage of universal hashing.

So: the hash function is chosen from the universal family when initializing the hash table, and it is possible (although not necessary) to change it whenever a rehash occurs -- but not after adding or inserting single elements.

Comment: Thanks, but the textbook says that the definition of "universal" is the collection satisfies the number of hash functions h for each pair of distinct keys k, l , for which h(k) = h(l) is at most |H|/m, and in the proof, it says the number of keys other than k that hash to the same slot as k, is (1/m + 1/m + ... + 1/m) = n/m = load factor. I think it's not equal to the load factor, because the definition of "universal" only says the NUMBER of functions for each pair values. When a particular hash function has been chosen, it doesn't change, and so not all the probabilities are equal to 1/m.

Comment: @CHENSai: I 'm not following. What is your question/objection exactly?

Comment: Sorry, the question I asked unclearly above has been solved. Now I have a new question: the textbook says the uniform hashing is that the probe sequence of each key is equally likely to be any of the m! permutations of <o,1, ..., m-1>. Given a key, using uniform hashing to generate a probe sequence. Then given the same key again, using the same uniform hashing again, does it generate the same probe sequence or generate another probe sequence randomly since "it is equally likely to be any of the m! permutations"?

Comment: @CHENSai: If the key is the same and the hash function has not changed (e.g. as part of a rehash in the meantime) then obviously the probe sequence will also not have changed.